# 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an "Event" model and it has a `many2many` field with default user model.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_hour = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    end_hour = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, I am trying to update this `many2many` field like following;

```
//my serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id',)


class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = UserSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'users')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        submitted_users = validated_data.get('users')
        if submitted_users:
            for user in submitted_users:
                user_instance = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
                instance.users.add(user_instance)
        instance.save()
        return instance

//views.py

class UpdateParticipants(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
```

However, I am getting an error like in the belowe image

[image]

// this is the APIView that I used

[image]

Comment: Can you provide User Model.

Comment: @marin user model is the default user model which is provided by django

Comment: are you sure you use `GET` or `PATH` method?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code below?

## Models

## Example

```
class UserModel(User):
    pass

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_hour = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    end_hour = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='event_user') # Set related name to User object for Rest Framework

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## Serializer

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    users = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Event
class Userserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    event_user = EventSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        event_user = validated_data.pop('event_user', None)
        print (event_user)

        if validated_data:
            for attr, value in validated_data.items():
                if attr == 'password':
                    instance.set_password(value)
                else:
                    setattr(instance, attr, value)
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

## Views

```
class EventView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self):
        qv = User.objects.all()
        serializer = Userserializer(qv, many=True)
        return Response(data={'users': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def put(self, request, user_id):
        instance = Event.objects.get(user=user_id)
        serializer = Userserializer(instance=instance,data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data={'users': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(data={'users': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

## URL-s

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>\d+)',EventView.as_view())
]
```

## JOSN exaple for put

## JSON

```
{
    "id":1,
    "event_user":[{
        "name":"Changed Name"
    }]
}
```

Comment: when I do that, I even cannot open the APIView. It gives me a error like following; TypeError at /participants/1/
'ListSerializer' object is not callable

Comment: Please see documentation for ManyToMayn relations: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model

Comment: I've already read it several times. setting read_only to true does not work for me

Comment: Thanks for your detail answers, it didn't work. I think the problem is, I cannot get data from validated_data. I tried to print it but, I couldn't. How can I print the validated_data

Comment: What's the problem with GET?